# Canceling Notification with OneSignal REST API

Tags: php, rest, push-notification, onesignal

So I'm trying to cancel notifications using the REST API of oneSignal. I have successfully sent them and scheduled them using the oneSignal REST API but canceling is proving to be difficult. Mostly it is because in the documentation the cURL is:

```
curl --include \
     --request DELETE \
 --header "Authorization: Basic NGEwMGZmMjItY2NkNy0xMWUzLTk5ZDUtMDAwYzI5NDBlNjJj" \
https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications/{notificationId}?app_id={appId}
```

This is my PHP code so far:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$httpHeader = array(
      'Authorization: Basic MY_REST_API_KEY'
    );
$url = "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications/" . NOTIFICATION_ID . "?app_id=" . APP_ID;

$options = array (
  CURLOPT_URL => $url,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $httpHeader,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "DELETE",
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I'm not too sure how to convert the shell to php and right now it is not deleting the notifications. the $response isn't returning anything meaning it is not working. Any help would be awesome.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to add one more option to my options array so basically this:

```
$options = array (
  CURLOPT_URL => $url,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $httpHeader,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "DELETE",
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE
);
```

That allowed the request to go through!